# How would you log into AWS if you lost your phone which provides 2-factor authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The FAQ directs you to a page which doesn't exist!
http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAM FAQ page's link contains a typo... the word "forms" is misspelled "foms."

The corrected link takes you to the following page, which is valid:

https://aws.amazon.com/forms/aws-mfa-support/